# Adding text to a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do something very simple but somehow its not working.

I have 4 divs on the right, and one blank div on the left. I want the left div to show certain text, depending on which div I hovered on, on the right.

It's very simple, but somehow I am missing something.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 Left">
    <h3>left:</h3>
    <div id="roles">
       <button class="role" id="role_1">
           Role_1
       </button>
       <button class="role" id="role_2">
           Role_2
       </button>
       <button class="role" id="role_3">
           Role_3
       </button>
       <button class="role" id="role_4">
           Role_4
       </button>   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12-col-xs-12 right">
    <div id="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#role_1').hover(function(){
        $('#right').html('<p>Text_1</p>')
    });
     $('#role_2').hover(function(){
        $('#right').html('<p>Text_2</p>')
    });
     $('#role_3').hover(function(){
        $('#right').html('<p>Text_3</p>')
    });
     $('#role_4').hover(function(){
        $('#right').html('<p>Text_4</p>')
    })

})
```

This is just a basic code to write "Text" when it hovers over #role_1. Somehow it doesn't work. It works on JSFiddle

Here is my CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
```

EDIT: It works on JSFiddle. Somehow it is not working on http://hellosimpletax.com/#/

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twsL2fgq/5/)

Thank you!

Comment: $('#roles').mouseleave(function(){
           $('#right').html('')
          })

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/twsL2fgq/2/

Comment: check in console.. is https based url loading?

Comment: You forgot all your `;` too.

Comment: Have you tried $('#role_1').on('mouseover', function(){
        $('#right').html('<p>Text_1</p>') ?
    });

Comment: Have you tried after placing the code inside a controller? It is not at all listening to mouseover event.

Comment: YES IT WORKS! Thank you @krishna

Comment: @Nitsorn Wongsajjathiti did it work after placing code in controller? vote please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

OP got it working by moving his code into the Angular controller as @krishna suggested in a comment after we noticed that the view wasn't full loaded on document ready.

Try this:

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/twsL2fgq/6/

```
$(function(){
  $('#dev').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#right').html('<p>Text_1</p>');
  });
  $('#des').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#right').html('<p>Text_2</p>');
  });
  $('#eng').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#right').html('<p>Text_3</p>');
  });
  $('#art').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#right').html('<p>Text_4</p>');
  })
  $('#roles').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('#right').html('');
  })     
})
```

A couple unrelated asides:

- If you specify `col-md-6`, you shouldn't need to declare `col-xs-12` since Bootstrap treats mobile as its baseline and should automatically stack your columns if you're using `container-fluid`
- The preferred way to attach event handlers with jQuery is by using [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Not even in the demo? The text shows up below the buttons.

Comment: It works in the demo (like other answers in this post) I don't get why it doesnt work on my localhost.

Comment: Do you have the page live somewhere that we can see? Are you sure that jQuery is loaded before you run the document ready?

Comment: I don't think Angular has loaded your view yet when your script is run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90866/discussion-between-tracy-fu-and-nitsorn-wongsajjathiti).

Answer (score 2):

Check your console you will find error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Try this you just forget to close `#roles` selector

```
$('#roles').mouseleave(function(){ $('#right').html('') }) 
---------^
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/twsL2fgq/2)

Comment: Please make your answer more detailed.

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz what do you mean ?

Comment: @Makudex thanks for your advise just added some details

Comment: Thank you all, but somehow its still not working. I fixed all the syntax errors, no error in console.

Comment: @NitsornWongsajjathiti my demo is not working for you ? update your fiddle what code you have added.

Comment: @akash It works perfectly in theory (and in JSFiddle) but somehow not in my code. I really dont understand why. http://jsfiddle.net/6p3h4mu3/